# Hyperlinks on website using W3.CSS not working

Tags: html, css, w3.css

I am creating a website using a W3 template and using the w3 css file. Something in it is stopping my hyperlinks working. [Website](https://replit.com/@ErikStevenson2/w3-css-issue#index.html) something particularly in lines 473 - 490 of the CSS (show below) is causing the issue

```
 .w3-container:after,
.w3-container:before,
.w3-panel:after,
.w3-panel:before,
.w3-row:after,
.w3-row:before,
.w3-row-padding:after,
.w3-row-padding:before,
.w3-cell-row:before,
.w3-cell-row:after,
.w3-clear:after,
.w3-clear:before,
.w3-bar:before,
.w3-bar:after{
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both
}
```

I've removed the above code, and that removes the problem - however it introduces a formatting issue instead, so any advice would be gratefully received as my HTML skills are lacking in sorting this out myself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As soon as I remove those lines, hyperlinks start working, however, that also messes up the formatting of the page, really confused by this!

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you haven't close this div tag :

```
 <!-- First Grid -->
 <div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-64 w3-container">
```

Comment: Why -1 if is the right answer ?